# displaying data from mysql, displaying it in table

Tags: php

Im building a web site that will return results from mysql and display them on a web page.
I have no problem with storing the data in mysql or retrieving the data
 and displaying it on the web page.
When the data is returned to the page I want to store it in a table and run a loop so that for each record there will be a number incremented down the side like a list number.
Any help would be appreciated.
I keep running into errors with my code:

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }

    mysql_select_db("forloops", $con);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userinfo ORDER BY age DESC");

    echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th>Position</th>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    </tr>";
    $counter = 0;
        $position= 0;
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    if($counter <=10){

            echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>" . $position . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['age'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            $counter++;
            }
    echo "</table>";
    mysql_close($con);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**The problem with your current code is that you're only fetching the first row from the query, take a look at how I've down it below:**

```
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
    <th>Position</th>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Age</th>
</tr>";
$counter = 0;
    $position= 0;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { // This is new code
    if($counter <=10){

        echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $position . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['age'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        $counter++;
    }
} // This is new code
echo "</table>";
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

If you notice, I've created a loop around the echoing of the table's rows `<tr>` and cells `<td>`.

This `while` loop will go through each row returned from the query.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more then one result from database, you should use:

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 //process one row
}
```

Using your way, $row is always the same.
And secondly, if i saw right, you dont increase $position variable.

Comment: i was writting while you post it, so sorry for double :)