# Display data retrieved from MySQL in a rows / tabular form in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, image, rows

I have written some data on MySQL database and would like it to be displayed on the webpage in the form of rows and coloumns.

```
    echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr>";
    for($i=0; $i<$num_results; $i++) {
        echo "<td style=\"width:30%\";>";
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); 
        echo htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($row['bagimage'])); 
        echo "<img src=".htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($row['bagimage'])). " width=\"130px\" height=\"130px\" />";       
        echo "</strong><br/>Bag Type: ";
        echo stripslashes($row['bagtype']);
        echo "<br/>Price: ";
        echo stripslashes($row['price']);
        echo "<br/>Description: ";
        echo stripslashes($row['description']);
        echo "</p>";
        echo "</td>";
    }
        echo "</tr>";
   echo " </table>";
```

Now the data displayed here is all in just one row. I want it to display 4 in one row.
Like this
X X X X
X X X X
X X X X

The data consists of Image, price, description and type. which makes one cell of a table.

Now do we need a table here or can this be done in another way? Please help.

Also, The image code is kinda wrong as the image does not really display. Can someone please help me with the coding to be able to display the image correctly? should i be using stripslashes or mysql_real_escape_string instead? or is the entire code wrong? 
note: 'bagimage' is the coloumn name for image which is of type longblob.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14773603/displaying-data-from-mysql-displaying-it-in-table

Answer (score 0):

I just got an answer after some research.

just added  $results_per_row = 4;

and then inside the loop add this code:

```
if($i % $results_per_row == 0) {
echo "</tr><tr>"; }
```

you can also add line break instead of closing table row as per your code requirement.

However, I am still not able to figure out two things.

1) if the results are too many, more than say 100. How do display the results in more than one page or maybe the results will keep appearing as you scroll down using ajax maybe?

2) I am not able to get the images to display. I have tried everything possible.